# I have Affiliate Pro management system....I like to add path of Affiliate Pro in my codeigniter home page

Tags: php, codeigniter

My folder structure

[image]

My problem was I know how to add path in home page for php

```
include('affiliate-pro/controller/affiliate-tracking.php);
```

I added `require_once("affiliate/controller/affiliate-tracking.php");` in `home.php`...

please give me suggestion...

Comment: Can you explain more about your issue ?

Comment: Hi Noman   in my affliate document they given code as  include('affiliate/controller/affiliate-tracking.php);  for integrating to website. . My problem was i need to add this  path for my codeigniter...website....dint tracking

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the affiliate-pro system with Codeigniter. In your views (for example in your footer.php) include it this way:

```
<? include('affiliate-pro/controller/affiliate-tracking.php'); ?>
```

And when you're in a controller, use:

```
include '/home/bolzz/public_html/affiliate-pro/controller/record-sale.php';
```

Notice that if you decide to use the system while it's installed on another domain or root directory - you will have to enable 'allow_url_include=1' in php.ini and restart apache. Not recommended...